# Image not loading in tableview in iOS 10 on first time, but after scroll?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios10

I am getting problem while displaying images in tableview in iOS 10, but same code works bellow iOS 10, I have added snippet of my code bellow. Please help.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"InboxTableViewCell";

InboxTableViewCell *cell = (InboxTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[InboxTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
[cell setBackgroundColor:[cellColors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[cell.profileImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile.jpg"]];

return cell;
}
```

And  in the cell I am making image circular

```
 #import "InboxTableViewCell.h"
@implementation InboxTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // Initialization code


}

-(void)layoutSubviews{
    self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImageView.frame.size.width/2;
    self.profileImageView.clipsToBounds=YES;
    [super layoutSubviews];
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Comment: Is the corner radius code the problem? I bet your issue will still be there if you remove it, so we most probably won't need it to answer. Also, it's enough to do it once the view woke from nib, you don't need to set the layers properties repetitive.

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier` will never result in a nil cell so why check for it?

Comment: Also `layOutSubviews` gets called multiple times. So instead, do your circlyfying in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Or in the best case in `- awakeFromNib`. From a software design perspective, the view configures itself. Putting that in the viewController is just poor design.

Comment: Try put your cell setImage method to main queue. Like this
    `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [cell.profileImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile.jpg"]];
    });`

Comment: And add [yourCollectionView reloadData] to main queue too?

Comment: This is bad practice and by no means should you do it this way.  But try assigning the image to your imageview using a tag and let us know if it renders properly.  For example:
    `UIImageView *profileImageView= (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    profileImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profile.jpg"];`

Comment: Make sure that you assign the tag for the UIImageView in attributes inspector within your main.storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the answer and I am my own question now.
we just have to wright it in drawRect method and thats it.

Happy Coding...

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius=_profileImageView.frame.size.width/2;
    [_profileImageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [_profileImageView layoutIfNeeded];
    [_profileImageView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in -(void)layoutSubviews method of InboxTableViewCell, call    [super layoutSubviews], before setting cornerRadius  .. you are setting before applying layout so your image frame before [super layoutSubviews] would be 1000 hence you are setting cornerradius to 500. 
After autolayout applies, image size become small and 500 corner radius on small image will hide image.

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImageView.frame.size.width/2;
    self.profileImageView.clipsToBounds=YES;

}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: Download this add into your project and import

Comment: Yes I tried this also, but not works, I m just trying to set local image. Thanks

Comment: #import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

Comment: No IBOUTLET are there